# creating dataset if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I'm brand new to the community and as well as I am to r. Here is an example part of my data set:

```
brettcontrol <- data.frame(rep.sw=c(NA,"sw","rep","sw"), RT=c(1:4) )
brettcontrol

  rep.sw RT
1   <NA>  1
2     sw  2
3    rep  3
4     sw  4
```

So if you see some of the the values under `rep.sw` are `"sw"` and `"rep"`. What I am trying to do is create an if statement that says `if rep.sw = 'sw' then...` it put all the `RT` values into a data frame called `sw`, and if the `rep.sw = "rep"` it will put all the `RT` values into a data frame called `rep`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

All the best,
Brett

EDIT: I did what DMT suggested and it worked perfectly! Afterwards I just used the na.omit(sw) command so that I could run the means and SD for each group! Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: why an if statement? you could just subset the data frame based on specific values in `rep.sw` in a single step

Comment: As @rawr suggests, you can easily enough just do `sw <- brettcontrol[brettcontrol$rep.sw=="sw",]` or `sw <- subset(brettcontrol, rep.sw == "sw")` - I suggest taking a read of a tutorial site like: http://statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Comment: Yeah, that was ignorance on my part. Thank you for setting me straight. :)

Answer (score 2):

not sure the form of the resulting dataframes (whether they'll just be one column? or they already exist?) but here's one way to get the values you want

```
sw<-brettcontrol$RT[brettcontrol$rep.sw=="sw"]
rep<-brettcontrol$RT[brettcontrol$rep.sw=="rep"]
```

where sw and rep are vectors, feel free to convert them to dataframes or use as you wish

Comment: thelatemail got it by 4 seconds! mine just adds $RT to specifically pull those values

Answer (score 1):

Try `split` with `list2env`.

It will assign two new data frames, `rep` and `sw`, to the global environment, and NA will be removed in `split`.

```
> ls()
# [1] "brettcontrol"
> list2env(split(brettcontrol[-1], brettcontrol$rep.sw), .GlobalEnv)
> ls()
# [1] "brettcontrol" "rep"          "sw"        
> rep
#   RT
# 3  3
> sw
#   RT
# 2  2
# 4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
swdf = data.frame(brettcontrol[brettcontrol$rep.sw=="sw",][,-1])
names(swdf) = 'sw_RT'
repdf = data.frame(brettcontrol[brettcontrol$rep.sw=="rep",][,-1])
names(repdf) = 'rep_RT'

> swdf
  sw_RT
1    NA
2     2
3     4

> repdf
  rep_RT
1     NA
2      3
```